# PHP via CLI - cant load extensions

Tags: php, windows, xampp, command-line-interface

I opened the CLI (Windows 7 as Admin) calling "php" without setting any environment variable(!) and got a few error-messages that describes php unable to open extensions.

For example:

```
PHP Startup:
bz2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
```

Another one's saying:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library "\xampp\php\ext\php_exif.dll" - The specified module was not found.
```

followed by many similiar messages. I'm running PHP in xampp located at **D:**\ and - *remember* - haven't set any path-variable yet. I tried setting it (**path**-variable) without any affection on the errors.

I'm running **PHP 5.3.8**

I'm wondering why there is no Driveletter shown in the error messages. May that be the cause of the Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is pretty simple - you must find extension with matching API version. Yours looks veeeery old.

Comment: Thank you. But where to find the exact ones?

Comment: Oh. Hard to tell, i don't use php at windows. But before i searched by "libname phpversion windows"

Comment: Fixed by commenting out the wrong extensions. Since then, my CakePHP App is not displaying anything anymore but anyways. Cant find all DLLs for the correct PHP-Version i've installed. For me its a poverty certificate of PHP not to give any fast possibility to fix this.. Poor.

Comment: My  best guess is to use virtuall machine or low power dedicated box with some server linux aboard. It may seem hard to use in the beginning, but then you'll see power and simplicity. Besides most part of hosting comanies use linux so writing software on the same platform will help you avoiding migration problems.